# Play/Pause Video Player Button Toggle Only Working Once

Tags: jquery, html, video, playback, pause

I am currently working on building a video player for my site, but I keep encountering issues when it comes to the play/pause end of things. I have a single button intended to toggle between playing and pausing, obviously. However when attaching the following code to that button, I play it and then pause it fine the first time. But when I go to resume it, it fails to work and the displayed video begins to slowly tile into black and no longer plays at all. I've dug through everything I could find on the internet with no success. I can't seem to get it working in even it's most basic form.
Here is my code that I currently have starting with the html side:

```
    <div id="video-container">
        <video id="selectedVideo" width=1000 poster="">
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>

    <div class="controls-container">
        <img id="play-button" src="~/Content/Images/Player/play-button.png" />            
    </div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var video = $('#selectedVideo').get(0);
var playButton = $('#play-button');

(window).load(function () {
    playButton.on('click', function () {
        playpause();
    });
});

function playpause() {
    if (video.paused || video.ended) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
};
```

I'm really hoping someone has some idea of why this isn't working. I've spent hours trying to figure it out and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: `$("body").on('click',playButton, function () {playpause();});` try with this

Comment: function playpause() {
        if (video.paused || video.ended)
            video.play();
        else if ( video.isPlaying())
            video.pause();
        else
            video.play();
    };

Comment: That failed too. I was hoping it'd be that simple. I did add logging for the button and found out it played, paused, played twice, then paused again in the process; not sure if that's relevant to the problem, but still a problem nonetheless. Tony, I'll give yours a shot real quick.

Comment: Tony, "video.isPlaying is not a function" is returned. I did a quick Google search and found nothing about an 'isPlaying' anywhere. Am I missing something?